# data sending issue with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble to solve a simple ajax function

I want to send php variables with ajax to another page if the user click on a link

Javascript

```
function sendData(a, b, c, d)
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "page.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d},
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.location.href="page.php"; 
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,error_string,error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<button  onClick="sendData(<?php echo $a ?>, <?php echo $b ?>, <?php echo $c ?>, <?php echo $d ?>)"> click </button>
```

Comment: What problem do you have exactly ?

Comment: the data are not sent to page.php. It seems that the script is not read. Neither the function success or error is executed

Comment: beacuse the ajax call is not the same page that you are loading.... you can not make an Ajax call and naviagte to the page. If you want to navigate to the page, than you should be submitting a form, not an Ajax call. If you do not want to go to page.php, than you should be stopping the click action.

Comment: What do you do in page.php ? Did you try to echo any of the variables ?

Comment: in page.php I want to use the variables and execute a query

Comment: @Espaccarelolo I do not understant

Comment: @JaromandaX onClick="sendData(<?php echo $a ?>, <?php echo $b ?>, <?php echo $c ?>, <?php echo $d ?>)"> in the browser contains the real variables values. And all of them are string

Comment: In the browser it looks like <a href="page.php" onClick="sendData('sport', 'family', 'friend', 'fruit')"> click</a>

Comment: do you expect the page page.php to load in the browser? aka you go to that page? if yes, you should not be using an ajax call.

Comment: Yes I want to go to the page.php. So what should I do ?

Comment: than you should not be using Ajax, you should either use get and use a querystring, or you will need to build a form and post it to that location.

Comment: Please can you give me an exemple on how to do it? @epascarello

Comment: You should not use `<a>`(means a link), change it to `<button>`, because the browser would take navigate to `page.php`  when you click the `link` , your won't get ajax response on your `new page` console. So just change it like that: `<button onClick="sendData(<?php echo $a ?>, <?php echo $b ?>, <?php echo $c ?>, <?php echo $d ?>)"> click </button>
`

Comment: @RazonYang I think it is a good solution but like that the data are not sent to page.php I use print_r($_POST) and the array is empty in page.php

Comment: I edited the question. Pleas check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.location.href="page.php";
```

the code above will redirect to `page.php` after getting a success ajax response, you won't get any data from previous ajax request in a new page(new GET request).

The ajax request already done and print it's response to console, and the new request is a GET request without data, so you will got an empty array(print_r($_POST)) in `page.php`.

A simple way to see what response you got, just comment or delete the code above, and then check ajax response in console.

If you want to pass data to other pages, you can store data into `session`, and then retrieve it from session in the other page.

PS: It is very helpful to turn on your browser development tools(such as google chrome `Network`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<button  onClick="sendData('<?php echo $a ?>', '<?php echo $b ?>', '<?php echo $c ?>', '<?php echo $d ?>')"> click </button>
```

you forgot single quotation